# Generating admin user from the Seed() method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-membership

I'm building a project where the user can access a CMS like admin system (I'm using the built in login that comes with MVC 4 projects). Each site will store the data in it's own SQL CE database. I want to publish the project without any existing db, and then let Entity Framework create it for me on the first hit.

The problem is that I can't let the /Account/Register method be [AllowAnonymous], so I need to have an already existing admin account in the "Users" table.
I want to have a "superuser" account that is already there when the db gets created, and then through this account I will log in and create a user account for the customer that is going to be using the CMS.

Is this possible, or do I need to drop this idea and just publish the project with an existing db?

If you have any other smart solutions, I'm all ears!? ;)

PS. The reason why I don't want to publish the site with a db is that I might accidentally overwrite any existing data if I do some bug fixes and forget to exclude the db from the project before deployment (for already existing sites etc).
I also have it set up so the Seed method fills the database with "starup" values, so the user starts with a clean slate.

Hopefully someone have any good ideas. I've tried searching but I couldn't really find what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution here:
http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.se/2013/01/seeding-customizing-aspnet-mvc.html

/ Mikael